# Is it bad for a potential grad schooler to take Abstract Algebra and Real Analysis my last year?

Tags: soft-question

I'm taking Abstract Algebra and Real Analysis my last year. I've already taken the following:
Calc 1-3
DiffEQ
Complex Analysis
Operations Research
Linear Algebra
Mathematics Foundations
Theory of Numbers
Advanced Stasticis

I'm worried that grad schoolers won't think I will do good in those courses because I don't have proof of good grades in time of application but I have gotten A's in all the other ones.

What do you think?

Comment: It is definitely troubling but if you have strong letters of recommendation, you could overcome the deficit. What was your complex analysis course like? What text did you use?

Comment: We used Saff))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Saff isn't a very rigorous text unfortunately. Have you done research or any independent projects? What kind of universities are you looking at applying to and what branch(es) of math interest(s) you?

Comment: If you have strong letters of recommendations and decent GRE scores you should definitely be able to get into graduate school somewhere.  You should get your first semester grades in by the time applications are due so if you do very well in your algebra and analysis courses that will help a lot.  You might even get a letter of recommendation from one of those professors if appropriate.  Always apply to a range of schools including safety schools and be realistic.

Comment: I am interested in dynamical systems. I've worked with Dr. Castillo-Chavez at Arizona state University in Dynamical Systems at his REU there last summer and I worked at Mayo SURF program as a math modeler with disease and some biology research the previous summer.

Comment: I also got a 170Q on the general GRE and a 900 on the Mathematics Subject GRE when I took it a couple months ago.

Comment: Should I think about taking a summer AA and RA course at some university that offers it online and have it transfer to my institution so I'll have the A's on file?

Comment: I've also done 1 big research modeling project with an advisor here at the Univesity and wrote an Honors program Thesis on it and presented it at our annual Research conference.

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot going for you.  I am assuming you are finishing up junior year now.  I don't know anything about online courses in advanced math.  I would definitely make sure you do very well in your courses next year, and you should have your first semester grades out by application time.  Apply to a wide range of schools, from your dream schools to the worst school you would consider going to.

Comment: If you got a $900$ on the subject GRE, you needn't worry about grad school applications so much. This is a HUGE boost to your application.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience, the undergrad classes served as the pre-reqs for the grad classes, and the grad classes you take are much more dependent on your course of study and the school you attend. There are grad students at my school who began at the same time as me and I have only had a few courses in common with them (both math majors).

That being said, real analysis is a must. You could probably get away without abstract algebra as long as you know how to write proofs and some key vocabulary (groups, rings, fields, homomorphism, isomorphism, etc.). But again, this may be specific to my personal experience.

I think the best thing to do if you know you are going to study math in grad school is to start taking the math courses that interest you now. No matter what field you end up studying you're going to have to go back and re-visit some undergraduate content that you never studied, don't remember, or wasn't covered in enough detail. That's what your classmates, teachers, and websites like this one are for. Grad school is supposed to be your passion, so do what you like and enjoy yourself!:)

Comment: I would argue that algebra is actually more necessary than analysis. You can do algebra without analysis of course but doing high level analysis is impossible without algebra. Most recent analysis (since the 30s/40s) is very, very laden with algebra. However knowing real analysis is necessary of course in the sense that we should learn as much as possible ;).